# Why isn't database decryption working after failing over to the standby?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, service-master-key

We added a new node (N2) to our SQL Server 2019 cluster. On existing N1, decryption queries works fine but when we failover to N2, decryption is failing. The database master key on N1 is encrypted by the service master key.
Question is do I need to backup the service master key from N1 and restore it on N2 after failover in order for decryption to work on N2?

Comment: Doesn't sound like you are using TDE. You may want to check this article:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/password-required-when-trying-to-add-a-database-having-a-master/ba-p/1029357

Answer (score 2):

> If you use transparent data encryption (TDE), the certificate or
> asymmetric key for creating and decrypting other keys must be the same
> on every server instance that hosts an availability replica for the
> availability group. For more information, see Move a TDE Protected
> Database to Another SQL Server.

[AGs and TDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/prereqs-restrictions-recommendations-always-on-availability?view=sql-server-ver16#TDEdbs)

So not the Service Master Key, but the certificate in master that protects the database encryption key:

[image]

See also [Move a TDE Protected Database to Another SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/move-a-tde-protected-database-to-another-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)